# Does npm install exclude dev dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I am in a Node.js project and run `npm install`, npm installs both, dependencies and dev dependencies. If I do not want to install the dev dependencies, I can run `npm install --production`.

Question 1: If I do *not* provide `--production`: Are the dependencies' dev dependencies installed, too, or only their actual dependencies?

---

Now, what if I am in a Node.js project and install a new dependency, something such as:

```
npm install foo
```

This installs `foo`'s dependencies, of course.

Question 2: But what about its dev dependencies? Are they installed, too, or are they skipped?

Comment: have you tried this?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run npm install by default both dependencies  and devDependency dependencies are also installed. Because if once is going to develop a package, we would download it e.g. from git and go to root folder and run.

```
npm install
```

so you would expect to have devDependencies to.

```
npm install "$package"
```

doesn't install the devDependencies by default. But if you really want to install development packages in that case, you can set the dev config option to true:

```
npm install "$package" --dev
```

Answer (score 6):

**Answers to your questions:**

1. Yes dev dependencies will be installed in `npm install` only way it wont install dev dependencies is when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`
2. No dev dependencies of your external modules won't be installed see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies)

Comment: ohh, I'm used to using `NODE_ENV` of `prod` :(

Answer (score 0):

Node applications use multiple methods to maintain dependency versioning up to date but there are multiple dependency types that need to be considered.  Dependencies are found in a node application's root directory within the package.json file.  I will go through the different dependency types and list some defining features or characteristics:

**Dependencies:**
These are specified in a simple object that maps a package name to a version range.  The version range is a string which has one or more space-separated descriptors.  Dependencies can also be identified with a tarball or git URL.

npm install  from a directory that contains package.json
npm install $package on any other directory
dependencies are required to run
Installed transitively: if A requires B, and B requires C. then C gets installed, otherwise B could not work, and neither would A.
**devDependencies:**
If someone is planning on downloading and using module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.  In this case it's best to map these additional items in a devDependencies object, which is not installed when the user is installing the package unless specifically passing in --dev.  These are typically installed when doing a traditional npm install from the root of the package.

npm install on a directory that contains package.json, unless the developer passes the --production flag.
not installed on npm install "$package" on any other directory, unless you give it the --dev option
Are not installed transitively
**Other Dependency types:**
These are less commonly used but may serve a purpose.

peerDependencies
optionalDependencies

Answer (score 0):

This question is stale but the other answers in here are not correct, so far as I can tell. From the OP :

> Question 1: If I do not provide --production: Are the dependencies' dev dependencies installed, too, or only their actual dependencies?

Another answer here states that 'yes' the `devDependencies` will be installed, however that is not the case for `devDependencies` of dependencies. [The NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install) is not clear on this :

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json... With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`.

Testing locally I confirmed that this rule only applies to the `devDependencies` of the root package. Transitive `devDependencies` are not installed.

> Question 2: (re: installing a new package, eg. `npm install foo`) But what about its dev dependencies? Are they installed, too, or are they skipped?

Same answer, the `devDependencies` are not installed.

Note the above applies wether or not the `--production` flag is included, in none of these cases are `devDependencies` of dependencies installed. All the `--production` flag serves to do is include or exclude `devDependencies` of the root package.

To me this makes sense semantically - the point of `devDependencies` is to indicate dependent packages that are not required at runtime, they're only required during development, up to the time of publishing. Put another way, you wouldn't want every one of your dependency packages installing it's own testing libraries, they won't be used!